# How can i pass a File to an HTTP form in Flask?

Tags: python, html, http, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to pass an instance of an object to a HTTP form to be modified, including a file field.

I try with this:

```
...

form = AnnuncioForm()
form.descrizione.data = annuncio_db['descrizione']
file = open('./images/default.jpg', 'rb')
form.immagine1.data = FileStorage(file)

...

return render_template('modifica_annuncio.html', id=id, form=form)
```

If i try to print `print(form.immagine1.data)`, it print a FileStorage object but in the site it doesn't appear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gANEZ.png)

Comment: `FileStorage` is for uploading files to the server, not for reading files on the server.

Comment: You don't pass a file to the form. The user uses the file input to select a file that's already on their computer and upload it to the server.